# Can you update indesign text after merging a document?

Tags: excel, csv, merge, adobe-indesign

I know that you can link text to an indesign document and it will show as a "link" that you can update whenever the text file has changed. I'm wondering if there is any way to have this link option after merging a CSV document to indesign. The link appears in indesign until just before I literally merge the document, but sometimes there are a number of changes that are made to my text and would be great if I can update it in excel and have the changes automatically made in my indesign document. Than you!

Comment: I use excel documents in CSV form to merge text and image links into Indesign. Unfortunately to my knowledge once the information is merged using the data merge function in Indesign, I can't seem to find a way to update the information using the links panel

Comment: I confirm.  You may consider EasyCatalog for those kind of after pagination updates.